# Sublime Text Won't Find htdocs

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, htdocs

I'm trying to open a file in htdocs directory which is on my desktop but when I click on open folder on Sublime Text 2 it doesn't show htdocs as a directory. However I can open a file in htdocs using Sublime Text by simply clicking on it. I tried to display the path of an index.php in a browser but it only shows "." instead of the path.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the folder project at your Sublime Text, just go to Project/Add folder to Project and browse it, add a whole project or just add htdocs folder if you want, so you also can see your folder project, just go to View/Side bar/Show side bar and you can find a file search it by name with the shortcut `Ctrl + P`

Answer (score 1):

I found that even if I create a shortcut of htdocs on my desktop the path stays the same. So for example "C:\xampp\htdocs..". I had to find that directory. In case if anyone else has the same problem.